# Testing a method that has a `try-catch` inside it using XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xctest

I'm trying to test a method with a `try-catch` in it but the test does not continue and the catch block is not being considered.

Let's say we have this:

```
class Foo
{
    func fetchData(request: NSFetchRequest) -> [AnyObject]?
    {
        var data: [AnyObject]? = nil
        do {
            data = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch {}

        return data
    }

    func fetchData(entity: String, predicate: NSPredicate?) -> [AnyObject]?
    {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entity, inManagedObjectContext: context)
        let request = NSFetchRequest()
        request.entity = entity
        request.predicate = predicate
        return fetchData(request)
    }
}

class SampleTests: XCTestCase
{
    // Assume that entity 'Employee' does not exist in the core data model
    func testFetchDataWithNonExistingEntity()
    {
        let foo = Foo()
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %i", 22345)
        let data = foo.fetchData("Employee", predicate: predicate)
        XCTAssertNil(data, "Data should be nil.")
    }
}
```

The test stops at `data = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)`.

Comment: it compiles? you defined the function fetchData with one parameter, than you call the same function with two parameters. something is wrong with your example

Comment: @user3441734 That's called function overloading, fyi.

Comment: aha, sory, you have both version there :-). the execution stop (crash) in line data = .... ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty catch block.

You could add:

```
catch let error as NSerror {
    // Do something with the error, e.g. return non-nil value.
    print("error \(error)")
    return []
}
```

to handle the error.

Some additional things to try:

- Make sure that **Debug executable** is checked on for your target's scheme under Test.
- If you have the **Test Failure** breakpoint turned on, that may be in conflict and you should turn that off.

Comment: @mownier Since your function is returning [AnyObject]?, you need to return an array of AnyObject or nil. Therefore, try returning the error inside an array.

Comment: @DanielZhang I tried but still the same. The test execution does not go through the `catch` block.

Comment: @mownier Are you sure that you are receiving an error? And if so, when you set a breakpoint on the return line in the catch block, you are getting no break there?

Comment: @DanielZhang Yep, I tried and unfortunately I was not getting a stop on that line. Should you try at your end.

Comment: @mownier If you can post a link to your project, I can take a look at it. I've already tested a corresponding setup on my end so I don't know what could be going on beyond what I've suggested.

Comment: @DanielZhang Unfortunately, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MyError: ErrorType {
    let msg: String = "my error"
}

// non throwing function
func f() {}

do {
    // will never go to chatch
    try f()
} catch {
    print("catch")
}

print("continue")

// throwing function 
func f2() throws {
    throw MyError()
}

do {
    try f2()
} catch {
    print("catch")
}
print("continue")
```

your data should be nil in both cases! if you execution stops inside do / catch block, it means that the execution failed there (something is wrong with your function)